# python audio listener losing quality after a few mins

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, speech

I'm trying to set up an persistent audio listener. The idea is to record bits of audio, send to Google's speech recognition API, and then run commands based on what was said. I know this has been implemented several times before; in fact, I'm borrowing a good amount of code (slightly adapted) from here:

https://github.com/jeysonmc/python-google-speech-scripts/blob/master/stt_google.py

I want it to be consistently running in the background. Right now, it works great for the first few minutes, but after awhile the recorder takes longer to stop recording (even with complete silence), and I'm not sure the right audio is being sent to Google, as the quality of the recognition falls off quite steeply. Note that I'm currently using a very aggressive try/except to get around the IOErrors that seemed to come about after recording the first bit of audio. Any solutions that are more elegant and/or effective are certainly welcome. My code is below:

```
#config
chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 48000
THRESHOLD = 180 #The threshold intensity that defines silence signal (lower than).
SILENCE_LIMIT = 2 #Silence limit in seconds. The max ammount of seconds where only silence is recorded. When this time passes the recording finishes and the file is delivered.

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

print "* listening. CTRL+C to finish."

all_m = []
data = ''
rel = RATE/chunk
slid_win = deque(maxlen=SILENCE_LIMIT*rel)
started = False

while (True):
    try:
        #listening loop, open new stream each time
        stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,channels = CHANNELS, rate = RATE, input = True, frames_per_buffer = chunk)
        data = stream.read(chunk)

        slid_win.append (abs(audioop.avg(data, 2)))

        #detect noise
        if(True in [ x>THRESHOLD for x in slid_win]):
            if(not started):
                print "starting record"
            started = True
            all_m.append(data)
        elif (started==True):
            stream.close()
            print "finished"

            #the limit was reached, finish capture and deliver
            filename = save_speech(all_m,p)
            google(filename)

            #reset all
            started = False
            slid_win = deque(maxlen=SILENCE_LIMIT*rel)
            all_m= []

            print "listening ..."
    except IOError as e:
        print "Caught IOError"
        stream.close()
        pass
```

The rest of the code just involves conversion to flac and a request to Google.

To reiterate, my code works well for the first few minutes, provided there isn't a lot of background noise and the commands are spoken directly into the microphone. I've tried closing the PyAudio stream before any files were saved/sent to Google, in addition to moving around where the stream was opened (it was originally outside the main while() loop). Both of these changes seemed to help a little. However, since the recording indicators become increasingly inaccurate as time goes on, my hunch is that it has something to do with a "misalignment" of the sliding window. Could definitely be wrong though.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Way more efficient way would be to use Pocketsphinx in keyword spotting mode specifically designed for continuous listening. To try it you need to checkout latest development version from trunk and run spotting on a file:

```
     pocketsphinx_continuouos -kws "oh mighty computer" -infile file.wav
```

There will be no need for internet connection, noise removal, you will be able to tune detection threshold and keyword pronunciation.

You can use pocketspinx through Python API:

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-kws', "oh mighty computer")
decoder = Decoder(config)

decoder.start_utt('')
stream = open(path.join('file.wav'), 'rb')
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is definitely helpful and I'll give it a shot. I had actually originally planned on using Pocketsphinx, but since the ultimate deployment will be on a Raspberry Pi, the above implementation seemed easier as far as setup/installation goes. Do you have any thoughts on how to optimize my original code?

Comment: No, no thoughts. Streaming audio to google is broken by design.